# Any way to make postMessage work with HTTPS?

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain, bookmarklet, postmessage

I have a browser bookmarklet which loads an iframe on the page. I then need that iframe to be able to pass a string back to the parent window. The child page has the following function:

```
function post(m){
parent.postMessage(m,'*');
}
```

This works fine as long as the child page (the one loaded in the iframe) is on http. But when it's https the postMessage doesn't work. I have not been able to find any documentation of this, or any way to get around it.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

This happens both on FF and Chrome (haven't tried IE). To clarify: the iframe DOES load, it's just that the postMessage doesn't get executed. On an HTTP page everything works fine. The code I'm using to receive the string is as follows:

```
function listener(event){
if ( event.origin !== "http://www.mysite.com" )
return

if (event.data=="string1"){function1();}
if (event.data=="string2"){function2();}
}

if (window.addEventListener){
addEventListener("message", listener, false)
} else {
attachEvent("onmessage", listener)
}
```

Comment: What browser? Post the code of the message event handler on the other side. Are you sure the iframe is loading? Firefox changed recent so that by default insecure iframes will not load in a secure parent.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you need your morning coffee.

Here is  your fix:

```
if ( event.origin.replace('https:', 'http:') !== 'http://www.mysite.com'  ) return;
```

Comment: Did you hear that loud noise outside? That was the sound of my palm hitting my forehead. I think it was heard round the world....Thanks!